# What is the training accuracy of this model?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, lstm

Training accuracy plot

[image: 1]

I’m trying to classifiy ECG signals using LSTM and MATLAB, the above plot shows that the training accuracy of the system is 100% but when I apply this code to calculate and get the accuracy I get only 20%

```
LSTMAccuracy = sum(trainPred == Labels)/numel(Labels)*100
```

Training accuracy calculated

[image: 2]

Am I missing something here? Or there something wrong I did in my code?

Here is the configuration and the training code:

```
layers = [ ...
    sequenceInputLayer(1)
    bilstmLayer(100,'OutputMode','last') 
    fullyConnectedLayer(5)
    softmaxLayer
    classificationLayer
    ]

options = trainingOptions('adam', ...
    'MaxEpochs',1750, ...
    'MiniBatchSize', 150, ...
    'InitialLearnRate', 0.0001, ...
    'ExecutionEnvironment',"auto",...
    'plots','training-progress', ...
    'Verbose',false);

net = trainNetwork(Signals, Labels, layers, options);

trainPred = classify(net, Signals,'SequenceLength',1000);

LSTMAccuracy = sum(trainPred == Labels)/numel(Labels)*100
figure
confusionchart(Labels,trainPred,'ColumnSummary','column-normalized',...
              'RowSummary','row-normalized','Title','Confusion Chart for LSTM');
```

Comment: There's not really enough information here to answer the question because it doesn't say anything about the labels produced in `trainPred` or `Labels`.  Is it possible to put together a minimal example script that reproduces the unexpected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can be solved using the following line of code:

```
trainPred = classify(net, Signals,'SequenceLength','longest');
```